# How to get value of a tag inside modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code and i want the value from a tag.

```
  <div class="modal fade show" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
    labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: block;">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> 
   <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ingridiants  Detail</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="dvDetail">&nbsp;&nbsp;<table><tbody><tr><td>Name</td>
  <td>quantity</td></tr><tr><td>Chicken&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>1&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><a class="fa fa- 
  times" id="btnRemove" title="Delete" value="Chicken"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table> 
  </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
   dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have used following code to get value but value is undefined.

```
    $('body #dvDetail').on('click', function () {
        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this ingridients")) {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var CartId = $(this).closest('tr').find("btnRemove").val();
            alert(CartId);
            //Deletes the record with ID sent below
            $.post(
                '/RegisterFoods/DeleteIng/',
                { FoodName: CartId },
                function (item) {
                    tr.remove();
                }, "json");

            location.reload();

        }
    });
```

The alert is undefined. but all other code is working.

Comment: just use `#btnRemove` in your `find()` or better to use a class `.btnRemove` instead of id

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes.

1. Anchor `<a>` does not have `value` attribute, so you can use data `attr` as below
2. you have mistakes to find that it

```js
$('body #dvDetail').on('click', function () {
        var _t = $(this);
        if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this ingridients")) {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var CartId = _t.find("#btnRemove").data('value');
            alert(CartId);
            //Deletes the record with ID sent below
            $.post(
                '/RegisterFoods/DeleteIng/',
                { FoodName: CartId },
                function (item) {
                    tr.remove();
                }, "json");

            location.reload();

        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade show" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
    labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: block;">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> 
   <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ingridiants  Detail</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="dvDetail">&nbsp;&nbsp;<table><tbody><tr><td>Name</td>
  <td>quantity</td></tr><tr><td>Chicken&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>1&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><a class="fa fa- 
  times" id="btnRemove" title="Delete" data-value="Chicken"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table> 
  </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
   dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: You were trying to find out closest `tr` closest `tr` means if element finds nearest closest element then it will stop at that place. So you need to traverse all the occurrence of `tr` than you find `#btnRemove`

Try below code hope it will help you.

```js
$('body #dvDetail').on('click', function() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this ingridients")) {
    var tr = $(this).find('tr #btnRemove');
    var CartId = tr.attr('value');
    alert(CartId);
    //Deletes the record with ID sent below
    $.post(
      '/RegisterFoods/DeleteIng/', {
        FoodName: CartId
      },
      function(item) {
        tr.remove();
      }, "json");
    location.reload();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade show" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: block;">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> 
   <span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ingridiants Detail</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="dvDetail">&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>quantity</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Chicken&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>1&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                  <a class="fa fa- 
  times" id="btnRemove" title="Delete" value="Chicken"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```